# Select .NET Framework to Use In Visual Studio Application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

If I have different .NET frameworks installed on my machine (i.e. 1.1, 2.0. 3.0, 3.5), is it possible for VS2005 to select with which framework to create / compile an application (Winform/Webform)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible in Visual Studio 2005.  Visual Studio 2008 supports a version of multi-targeting which allows you to target either the 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5 framework.  It does not however allow you to target 1.0

ScottGu did a lengthy blog post on this subject that you may find worth a read:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/20/vs-2008-multi-targeting-support.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No, you need to use VS2008 to do that.

Even then you can only choose between 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2008, you can select a target framework (by right clicking onthe solution) but not from VS 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Only the 2.0 CLR based (that is 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5SP1) targetting is allowed unfortunately.